# Mobile apps for Pebble Smart watch

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, pebble-watch

Just curious if anybody tried creating mobile apps using IBM Worklight to connect to Pebble Smart watch? Please share your experience and approach.

Comment: Found some tutorial on Pebble SDK development: http://concentricsky.com/blog/2013/jun/pebble-sdk-watchface-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with Pebble Smart watches, however from what I understand from their website (https://developer.getpebble.com/) it looks like they provide SDKs for Android and iOS.

Worklight uses Cordova, which means you could write a Cordova plugin to run native code in your app, and this native code could use the Pebble SDK.

It looks like others already started looking into it: https://github.com/konsumer/phonegap-pebble